# Why aren't they using the bass clef

Tags: sheet-music

In the following score, why don't they just write the notes on the bass clef.  It would make things much easier to read.  You get points if you know what song it's from.  It's a rock n roll song from the 70s.[image: score]

Comment: It looks like a guitar part but written at sounding-pitch. And the chords are wrongly named. They should be: |Am  /  C(G bass)  /  |Fmaj7   /   /   /   |Am  /  C(G bass)  /  | And the rhythm in bar 2 is misspelt (US: misspelled). And it's too small to read! Hi logic1976. Welcome to Music P&T!

Comment: The one-word answer to this question is "incompetence."  That trait is also evident in the beaming of the second bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a guess on my part, and I've been wrong many times before, but it appears to be an attempt to multiply the number of octaves lower than middle C to be displayed in the sheet. I have to say I wouldn't have thought to do it this way myself. Here's another quick guess from just looking at the rhythm of the piece. Is it Dom-Diddy Dom Dom by Manfred Mann?

Answer (score 3):

Who's 'they'?  Not, I suspect a professional publisher.

Yes, it's unhelpful notation. Probably from a MIDI keyboard straight into a notation program.

Comment: I have seen a similar effect when importing a MIDI file, but it has picked the wrong instrument.  If that instrument is normally written using the treble clef, then you could see a really badly formatted result.